# How can I add more than 2 axes for MS Chart plot?

Tags: asp.net, mschart

My project will have a reporting ability with more that 2 Y axes. 
It would be ideal to manage doing something like [this](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Multi-Y_Demo), but using MS Chart.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was found within the Samples Environment for MS Chart:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart (see the WebSamples/ChartFeatures/Axis/MultipleYAxis sample).